Is it possible in Kotlin to mock an extension method that has argument overloads?
First question here!
I'm trying to do the following. I'll avoid library details but basically I'm trying to mock an extension method provided by the Kotlin Aws sdk library, where a method is added to the io.File class that turns an opened File into a Bytestream. Thing is, there's two overloaded methods for this. I've found ways to mock extension methods statically, and I can mock overloaded methods, but, I can't find a way.
To replicate this I'm running this small block. While also defining a single extension method in another Kotlin file.
Extension.kt
fun File.extensionFunc(string: String): Int {
    return string.toInt() + this.length().toInt()
}

Main.kt
val file = mockk<File>()

mockkStatic(File::extensionFunc)
every { any<File>().extensionFunc(any()) } returns 5

val result = file.extensionFunc("asdf")
assertEquals(5, result)

unmockkStatic(File::extensionFunc)

Which works fine! But if I add an extra extension method to File, same name, different arguments, I can't figure out how to have this work without having the real extension method called (which obviously fails since the mocked file instance can't return the length() function)
Extension.kt
fun File.extensionFunc(string: String): Int {
    return string.toInt() + this.length().toInt()
}

fun File.extensionFunc(long: Long): Int {
    return long.toInt() + this.length().toInt()
}

The main issue is that the mocckStatic doesn't compile to overload ambiguity.
Outside of this question's original scope
This is a simplification of my problem. My situation runs a bit deeper because I do not own these extension methods myself but they are located in imported .class files (with kotlin syntax) from this AWS library.
Here's a sample just in case, but this is outside of the question's scope, and I'm hoping to find a solution of my own if I get the other problem fixed.
package aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content

public fun java.io.File.asByteStream(start: kotlin.Long = COMPILED_CODE, endInclusive: kotlin.Long = COMPILED_CODE): aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content.ByteStream { /* compiled code */ }

What's different in my attempt here is that I'm trying to statically mock the whole class usingmockkStatic("aws.smithy.kotlin.runtime.content.ByteStreamJVMKt") but that doesn't do the trick either

This question is similar to: Mockk: Mock a global function with overloads. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
